# List of directory tree of multiple files

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, batch-file

I am trying to compile a list of all the files in four directories, each with a different path. I have the following code, and it is working, but not how I want it to

```
@echo off
tree d:\directory > c:\lists\4list.txt /a /f
tree e:\directory2 >> c:\lists\4list.txt /a /f
tree f:\directory3 >> c:\lists\4list.txt /a /f
tree g:\directory4 >> c:\lists\4list.txt /a /f
```

The output in 4list.txt has all the ASCII characters and spaces at the front of each line. It also has

```
+---Directory name
    filename1
    filename2
    filename3
```

listed at each directory in the tree. Is there any way that I can have it generate this list, WITHOUT all the special characters, directory names, spaces, extra lines, AND without the file extensions?

Basically, I am wanting to create this list of the 2200+ files, so I can copy and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet that I have conditional formatting setup on, that highlights duplicate filenames (may have duplicate video files, but with different formats .mkv, .mp4, etc.).

I know that I can manually go through the text file, and using Notepad's find/replace feature, I can "replace" all of the extensions with blank (""), and manually replace the extra characters and spaces at the beginning of each line as well as deleting the "+---Directory" names. However, this can be RATHER time consuming.

I am wanting to create this file, so that it can be scheduled to run once per day, and update the ever growing list of files on these drives.

If there's a way to have this list exported to an Excel document rather than a .txt file that would save me a step or two as well.

Comment: Would using this PS command help:
`gci -file "C:\test - copy" -recurse | % {$_.BaseName}` to form the start of what you want?

Comment: It's hard telling what you need exactly but see if a simple `DIR /S /B "d:\directory" >> "c:\lists\4list.txt"` but otherwise you may need to wrap that command in a `FOR /F` loop and then `ECHO %~NA` using substitutions to get just the file name portion of each value from the `DIR` command to only show the file name without the extension of the rest of the folder path each file resides.

Answer (score 0):

This link seems like it will help you. http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/build-directory-tree-structure-reports